# Matplotlib Contour Clabel Location

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I would like to control the location of matplotlib clabels on a contour plot, but without utilizing the manual=True flag in clabel. For example, I would like to specify an x-coordinate, and have labels created at the points that pass through this line. I see that you can get the location of the individual labels using get_position(), but I am stuck at that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way built into matplotlib to do that. You are supposed to either live with the default locations or go fully interactive with manual and using the mouse.

You might want to file this as a bug report upstream so they can improve their algorithms.

There are multiple options to work around this. The first one is to programmatically place text on the contour figure. You will not be able to reliably remove the lines underneath the text this way. Assuming you have a contour `c` you can find the contour lines in `c.collections`. For every contour line invoke `get_paths` and place your text on that path.

The other option would be to replace the code for manual placement (in  `matplotlib.contour.BlockingContourLabeler`) or tweak the code that finds the label positions (in `matplotlib.contour.locate_label`), but both functions are pretty dense. If you can come up with a working replacement for `locate_label` just overwrite the old method in your plotting macro

```
def your_locate_label(self, linecontour, labelwidth):
    # some magic
    pass

ar = np.array([[1,0], [0,1]]
c = matplotlib.contour(ar)
c.locate_label = your_locate_label

c.clabel()
```

Btw, if you use `ipython` you can easily view the function source from your interactive session with

```
%psource c.clabel
```

or directly invoke your `$EDITOR` on the file were it is defined with

```
%edit c.clabel
```

Comment: I didn't find this issue posted, so I made a new one: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/613

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there now is a way to control label locations!
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/642

```
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
manual_locations = [(-1, -1.4), (-0.62, -0.7), (-2, 0.5), (1.7, 1.2), (2.0, 1.4), (2.4, 1.7)]
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10, manual=manual_locations)
```

Comment: manual can be an iterable object of x,y tuples. Contour labels will be created as if mouse is clicked at each x,y positions.

Comment: Is there a way to allow automated labelling, and then loop through the labels to remove (and maybe improve) any that intersect the axes?

Comment: The labels with be placed on a contour **near** the locations given by `manual`.

Comment: I like the answer even though this isn't strictly what was requested. The manual locations can be copied and modified from the automatically generated output without too much trouble.