# Boundary points from a set of coordinates

Tags: python, scipy, geospatial

I have a set of lat,long points, and from this points I'd like to extract the points that form the boundaries, I've used convexhull, but for my purpouse is not enough as convehull just returns the most distant points that form the polygon where all the points fit, I need ALL the points that form the peremiter, something like the image I've attached.  What could I do? Is there some kind of package ready to use instead of implement any spatial algorithm?
Thanks
 [image]

Comment: I suspect you want the shape known as a 'concave hull': https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull.

Comment: @Karlovalntin You first need to clearly define when a point is to be considered as a "boundary point". In other words, why is the particular polygon you draw the "boundary perimeter" and not any other of the numerous polygons (not necessarily convex) one could possibly draw that would also include all points?

Comment: I need to have all the points that could conform the perimeter of a polygon with the minimum area.

Comment: The polygon that you show in the example is not even close to the minimum area.  Are you sure that is what you want?  Maybe you want an [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape)?

Comment: Yes, alpha shape is what I'm looking for @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: Just for reference, I've followed this method and it worked http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/

Answer (score 4):

You must use a package for convex polygons. Here is an example:

```
import alphashape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = put your points here (can be array)!
alpha = 0.95 * alphashape.optimizealpha(points)
hull = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha)
hull_pts = hull.exterior.coords.xy

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(hull_pts[0], hull_pts[1], color='red')
```

Comment: User beware - this method not optimal for large data sets.

Answer (score -1):

Use Concave hull (Alpha shape) instead.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you have all points (latitudes and longitudes) in two lists LATS, LONGS respectively, this python snippet cand do the trick. hullPoint will have the set of points that can draw the convex hull.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
allPoints=np.column_stack((LATS,LONGS))
hullPoints = ConvexHull(allPoints)
```

Comment: ConvexHull isn't necessarily the boundary!