# Is there a non-manual way to change matplotlib clabel locations?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib contour plot of wind speed (m/s) with contour labels using clabel. Unfortunately, the default clabel locations are poorly placed - see the top right corner:

[image: figure]

I would like to change this to make the plot easier to read.

I understand how to manually set the contour labels from the second response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791445/matplotlib-contour-clabel-location).

However, I have so many contours and multiple figures that it seems like a very impractical solution to do this manually. Is there a non-manual way to clean up the contour label locations? Also, could I have more than one contour label per contour without doing it manually?

Comment: May be if you do not label every line it's solve the problem.