# How to add multiple clabels per contour line

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, contour

I am creating a pcolormesh/contour plot of weather data. Adding contour labels using:

```
cs = ax.contour(lon,lat,temp_smooth,[32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58],colors='black',linewidths=0.5,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.clabel(cs, fmt='%d',fontsize=7)
```

How can I control the number of labels per contour line? It is very hard to track long contours with only a single label (see attached image). I am not able to find anything in documentation on this, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13015194/14277867) solution only allows me to control x/y position manually. I would like the automated placement, but simply a density control.

[image: Contour plot example]

Comment: you should add complete code for others to help you. If you data is private, then provide some synthetic data.